# How to open cshtml page in an old cshtml page using c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, window, knockout.js

I have a cshtml page that shows notes taken from a database in a grid. There is a createNote button that opens a pop-up where new notes can be added to the database. However, I don't want this to pop-up but to open in the same page as the grid. 
Can two cshtml's be combined, or should I make one cshtml containing both the grid and the add options, but only show the add options if the createNote button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best case would be to create a partial view and put all the new note related html + javascript inside it. And then include the partial view where ever you require.